# Python skips a single character on long windows cmd batch command lines

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, arguments, command-line-arguments

Here is a batch file `long.bat`

```
@echo off
python print_argv.py ^
 00234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 02234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 03234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 04234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 05234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 06234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 07234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 08234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 09234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 10234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 11234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 12234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 13234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 14234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 15234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 16234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 17234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 18234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 19234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 20234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 21234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 22234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 23234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 24234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 25234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 26234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 27234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 28234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 29234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 30234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 31234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 32234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 33234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 34234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 35234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 36234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 37234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 38234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 39234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 40234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 41234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 42234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 43234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 44234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 45234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 46234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 47234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 48234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 49234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 50234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 51234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 52234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 53234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 54234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 55234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 56234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 55234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 58234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 59234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 60234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 61234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 62234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 63234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 64234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 65234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 66234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 67234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 6823456789012345.6789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 69234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678^
 END
pause
```

that calls a python 3 script `print_argv.py`

```
import sys
for x in sys.argv:
    print(x)
```

and produces the following result:

```
print_argv.py
00234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
02234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
03234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
04234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
05234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
06234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
07234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
08234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
09234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
10234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
11234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
12234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
13234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
14234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
15234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
16234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
17234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
18234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
19234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
20234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
21234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
22234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
23234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
24234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
25234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
26234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
27234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
28234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
29234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
30234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
31234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
32234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
33234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
34234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
35234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
36234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
37234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
38234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
39234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
40234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
41234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
42234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
43234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
44234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
45234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
46234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
47234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
48234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
49234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
50234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
51234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
52234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
53234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
54234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
55234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
56234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
55234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
58234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
59234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
60234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
61234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
62234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
63234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
64234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
65234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
66234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
67234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
68234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
69234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
END
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why is the dot character from line 71 (the line starting with `68`) column 18 missing from the output?

It looks like python skips a single character (no matter if dot or other) around position 8192 (the legacy(?) windows command line length limit).

This poses a real problem on a batch file of mine that passes a lot of file names to a python script, because one of the file names gets crippled...

I'm on Windows 10 and this is my python:

```
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 02:47:15) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

Comment: I don't have an answer on your question although it looks like you have answered it already by yourself. I suggest that the batch file writes all the file names line by line into a file created in `%TEMP%`, passes just the file name of this list file to Python script with an option identifier which processes it and finally the batch file deletes the temporary list file after Python interpreter finished? That is the method used by nearly all applications written for usage from command line to bypass all the limits the command line environment have.

Comment: Or the Python script is extended to do all the tasks done at the moment by the batch file creating the long line because Python interpreter is definitely a more enhanced script interpreter than Windows command processor. By the way: On usage of command __SET__ the maximum length of __variable name + equal sign + variable value__ is 8191 characters although the entire command line can be longer. This limit for an environment variable table entry still exists also on latest Windows 10. On using enclosing `"` like in `set "variable=value"` the double quotes are included in 8191 bytes limit.

Comment: Strange, I am unable to reproduce it (I modified the *Python* code to also output each argument's index and length).

Comment: Perhaps instead of passing in parameters have the filenames in a config/text file that your python script can read from? I realize this doesn't answer your question but if it is limited by the OS then you would have to adjust your script anyhow.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error on Python 3.6.8, Windows 7 64-bit. I also added dot characters and special characters in the string, increased the string size, but always found all of them printed in my output.

Comment: Python 3.6.3 Windows 7 x64 - not reproduced. You could try to look with procmon  a real command line of python.exe for better understanding of what's a culprit.

Comment: @montonero: procmon reports an empty command line for the running python.exe

Comment: @amanb: upgrade to 3.6.8 does not change anything

Comment: That's quite unexpected. Are you sure you've looked a correct process?